# What's the voltage at A?

Tags: kirchhoffs-laws

[image]

I did KVL for both meshes and found the current passing through the 6 Ω resistor (that loop current), then multiplied this current by 6 Ω to get the voltage at A.

Wouldn't the electric potential at A just be 6 V, since between the 6 V independent voltage source and node A there is no resistor?

Which answer do I trust, the value found using KVL, or just 6 V since there is nothing to drop voltage between the 6 V source and A?

[image]

Comment: The negative terminal of the 6V supply is not at ground (or where you're measuring the voltage A from).

Comment: Hey Erik, I've added another diagram on the bottom here, so when it's grounded like this, what now? Would I just do (Va - 0) / 6 Ohms = Current found in KVL and solve for Va ??

Comment: Yes, that method will work.

Comment: So... let's say my current across that second loop was found to be 2 Amps, 2 = Va / 6 , Va = 12 V ? Why doesn't the 6V potential just flow to A?

Comment: Because your power supply isn't 6 volts referenced to your ground symbol. If the negative side of your volt source was connected to ground directly, then A would be 6 volts. But it isn't, the negative side of the voltage supply is connected through resistors to ground. In this case, all we know is that the voltage supply positive side is just 6 volts higher than the negative. You would have to actually work out what that negative side potential is. It could be 6 volts on the negative side and then 12 volts on the positive side. Or could be something else.

Comment: Remember that Voltage is also called "Potential Difference" - you always measure voltage between two points.  Very often one of the two points is called "Ground", and it is understood that when we say "the voltage at A is X", we really mean "the voltage at A relative to Ground is X".

Comment: I think this can be solved easily using thevenin/norton equivalence, first transform the voltage source and 2 Ohm resistor into an eqquivalent current source, then fold in the 4 ohm resistor and transform back into a voltage source. Now all the resistors are in series. Unless I made a mistake.

Answer (score 3):

You can decide to solve the problem in either of these two ways:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foQdEJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the left circuit the answer is just the voltage at A. In the right circuit the A node is at 6V but the answer requires you to also figure out the voltage at B.

Note... drawing the circuit this way might lead to a simpler approach to solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Remember you always need two nodes to specify a voltage.

If you look at the voltage on A wrt C it will be 6V:

[image]

But the voltage on A wrt B will be +(18/7)V because of the resistors.

Comment: I get 2.4 volts from A to B.

Comment: @PStechPaul 18/7 = 2.57142857143..

Comment: 6 ohms +2 ohms = 8 ohms. Parallel with 4 ohms = 2.67 ohms. This in series with 2 ohms = 4.67 ohms. 6 volts into 4.67 ohms => 1.28 amps. 0.428 amps through 6 ohms => 2.57 volts. Yeah, I made a mistake... :)